# All My Arrays are Mutating, but Why?

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I create `new Array(9)` it doesn't seem to be actually creating new arrays because when I attempt to mutate single array instances using `take`, it mutates all the arrays. Clearly they're each referencing the same array rather than being their own `new Array`, but why? And how do I fix this? I've tried [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) in various places, but all to no avail.

```
const Board = (fillWith = null) => ({
    winner: null,
    squares: new Array(9).fill(fillWith),
    winningSquares: []
});

const game = new Board( new Board() );

const take = (iA, iB, token) => {
  game.squares[iA].squares[iB] = token;
}

take(0,0,'x');
take(8,1,'o');

game.squares.map( (miniboard, i) => console.log({[i]: miniboard.squares}))
```

## Expected Result

```
{ 0: [ 'x', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null ] }
{ 1: [ null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null ] }
{ 2: [ null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null ] }
{ 3: [ null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null ] }
{ 4: [ null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null ] }
{ 5: [ null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null ] }
{ 6: [ null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null ] }
{ 7: [ null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null ] }
{ 8: [ null, 'o', null, null, null, null, null, null, null ] }
```

## Actual Result

```
{ 0: [ 'x', 'o', null, null, null, null, null, null, null ] }
{ 1: [ 'x', 'o', null, null, null, null, null, null, null ] }
{ 2: [ 'x', 'o', null, null, null, null, null, null, null ] }
{ 3: [ 'x', 'o', null, null, null, null, null, null, null ] }
{ 4: [ 'x', 'o', null, null, null, null, null, null, null ] }
{ 5: [ 'x', 'o', null, null, null, null, null, null, null ] }
{ 6: [ 'x', 'o', null, null, null, null, null, null, null ] }
{ 7: [ 'x', 'o', null, null, null, null, null, null, null ] }
{ 8: [ 'x', 'o', null, null, null, null, null, null, null ] }
```

## UPDATE:

Okay, this has been marked a duplicate of , and some have complained it's been answered a gazillion times. I get it. It feels very familiar, and I'm fully aware that objects and arrays are copied by reference which is why I've attempted to use the `new` operator for creating new boards. I've also tried the `Array.from` solution referenced, but that didn't help either. Maybe there's something else going on here and the answer will come to me in the morning, but for now here's a reference to the updated code I tried (but did not work) just to show that I did try what has been suggested as the answer to my "duplicate" question.

```
const Board = (fillWith = null) => ({
    winner: null,
    squares: Array.from({length: 9}, () => fillWith),
    winningSquares: null
});
```

Comment: Man, seriously 4K rep and such questions... objects are passed by refrence in Javascript - that's why nested arrays are mutating, among other things. That's also why people use deepClone or Immutable.js

Comment: Please look more carefully at the code before you knee jerk react. I'm aware objects are passed by reference. I'm using the `new operator` which should return a `new object` according to the MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

Comment: @ChrisGeirman Even your updated code is still facing the same issue. The reason the code is updating all the index is `const game = new Board( new Board() );`. Here the inner `Board` in invoked once and its reference is being passed to outer `Board`. Try below 
`let game = Board(); game.squares = game.squares.map(() => Board());` This way, for each index you are getting new reference.

Comment: @HassanImam thank you, you're exactly right. I knew I was missing something obvious. If you want to rewrite your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

`fill` gets a single instance and with it fills all rows. So your all rows refer to the same instance and because array is a reference type you have only on reference in each row. Instead of `fill` use `map` to return for each row its own array.